# create new ctype python

Tags: python, ctypes

below classes are in pure python, but the are a little slow on heavily dense calculation and lead to about 1 minute to do about 5 million action.

**the question**:

1. Is there any way to write them in C and import them to python for more speed?
2. how?

the usage is something like this:

```py
_cm=Unit(...)  # Unit
_m =Unit(...)  # Unit
a= 1*_cm  # UnitValue
b= 2*_m  # UnitValue
_m2 = _m**2  # Unit
b*a == 0.02 * _m2  # UnitValue
a*b == 200  * _cm2   # UnitValue # _cm2 is auto created unit based on Unit.__new__
b-a = 0.99*_m  # UnitValue
a-b = -99*_cm  # UnitValue
# and so on...
```

**NOTE:** the classes are bigger that what included here...

```py
class Unit(object):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if this unit not created before and if ues return before created-one.
        # useful for cmp between units.
        return created_or_new_unit_instance

    def __div__(self, other):
        return self * (other ** -1)     # self / other

    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        return other * (self ** -1)     # other / self

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self * other             # other * self


    def __mul__(self, other):       # self * other
        if isinstance(other, SUPPORTED_NUMBERS):
            return UnitValue(other, self)

        elif isinstance(other, UnitValue):  # FIXME DOUBLICATED!
            return (other.value * (other.unit * self))

        elif isinstance(other, Unit):  # multipling two units self * other
            # calculate the other exchange factor againest self in `v`
            if v == 1.0:
                # the bases may differ from self.bases or other.bases
                # so just create a new Unit and let __new__ handle doublication.
                return Unit(bases)
            else:
                return v * Unit(bases)

        return NotImplemented

    def __pow__(self, other, modulo=None):  # @UnusedVariable
        # create new powered unit.
        return new Unit
```

and the other Class:

```py
class UnitValue(object):
    def __init__(self, value, unit):
        self.value           = value
        self.unit            = unit


    def __add__(self, other):       # self + other
        if isinstance(other, UnitValue):
            o    = self.unit.get_unitvalue_in_this_unit(other)  # other is UnitValue
            v    = self.value + o.value
            return UnitValue(v, self.unit)

        if other == 0:
            return UnitValue(self.value, self.unit)

        return NotImplemented


    def __mul__(self, other):    # self * other
        if isinstance(other, SUPPORTED_NUMBERS):
            return UnitValue(other * self.value, self.unit)

        elif isinstance(other, UnitValue):
            return (self.value * other.value) * (self.unit * other.unit)

        return NotImplemented


    def __pow__(self, other, modulo=None):
        v    = self.value ** other
        u    = self.unit ** other
        if modulo:
            v    = v % modulo

        return UnitValue(v, u)


    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, UnitValue):
            vo   = self.unit.get_unitvalue_in_this_unit(other).value
        else:
            vo   = other
        if vo is None:
            vo = 0

        diff     = self.value - vo
        epsi     = 1e-10
        if abs(diff) < epsi: return  0
        elif    diff > 0:    return  1
        elif    diff < 0:    return -1
```

Comment: I'd think you'd save a lot of time just by using functions to do these operations, rather than relying on Python's method-resolution algorithm to be fast. E.g., `addEm(a,b)` rather than `a + b`.

Comment: @wtayyeb http://cython.org ?

Comment: @jpaugh: -1 -that is not how the language works. The "method resolution" algorithm is not slower than calling functions - maybe for a few native code opcodes, but the difference will pale if you are running Python anyway. Porting the operation themselves to native code, as the O.P. is asking for can, on the other hand, increase the performance several-fold.

Comment: Try also PyPy (http://pypy.org/) as a way to speed up this kind of code for free.

Comment: @ArminRigo, I tried pypy, no improvement seen on whole run. as pypy needs to worm-up and living program, but my project is not that case.

Comment: "about 1 minute to do about 5 million action" --- this certainly sounds like ample time to warm-up to me

Comment: @ArminRigo how ever i test it several times with pypy, no improvement at all. even a second.

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/108330/ a benchmark based on the code you posted: PyPy is 30 times faster than CPython.  I will not insist more about PyPy, but just saying, if you have only this kind of code, then it performs really well.  I guess you must have other code that slows it down, which you may want to mention here too, because it looks like it's relevant for any approach you take (not just PyPy).

Comment: @ArminRigo thanks for your effort. yes of-course the project is about 80000 lines of code in python. I have profiling the project several times and about 30% of whole project time is consumed in this two models. even in CPython or PyPy. no improvement for whole project. but as PeterVaro says I compile **all the project with cython** without anything changed. there is about 25%~35% speedup.